# Loading images of different sizes to train convolutional neural network

Tags: python, arrays, conv-neural-network

As I read during my research for my studies it is not necessary to feed a Convolutional Neural Network with input of the same size because we can apply the so called Spatial Pyramid Pooling as one layer to get this images of the same size before our Fully Connected Layers where we need same sized inputs. That's clear to me.
But I am completely lost how I can get the input, in my case a bunch of different sized images, in a useful dataframe or an array...

I know, how to load one image to Python. I took this code to get an array of one image:

```
from PIL import Image 
import numpy as np 

# Open image and make sure it is RGB - not palette 
im = Image.open('C:/Users/tobis/OneDrive/Desktop/Masterarbeit/data/2017-IWT4S-HDR_LP-dataset/crop_h1/I00001.png').convert('RGB') 

# Make into Numpy array 
na = np.array(im) 

# Check shape
print(na.shape)
```

But loading the next picture into this array is already a problem for me. Several questions arise:
1. Is an array a useful tool to work with these images of different sizes? Or do I need a pandas dataframe or something like this?
2. Is there a way to automate the process of loading this images to my dataframe/array?

I am very confused at the moment because I cannot imagine how to work around this issues because I do not understand how we can handle the loading of this images of different sizes and how Python works with these. I hope, my questions are more or less clear.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, multi-dimensional arrays (tensors) are very useful to store image representations of different sizes. Avoid Pandas for data input purposes - it is **much** less computationally efficient than numpy arrays or tensors (i.e. tensorflow or pytorch)
2. Absolutely. Keras has the [ImageDataGenerator class](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) for this express purpose. Some examples are on that page as well as from [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-load-large-datasets-from-directories-for-deep-learning-with-keras/):

```py
# example of progressively loading images from file
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# create generator
datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

# prepare an iterators for each dataset
train_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('data/train/', class_mode='binary')
val_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('data/validation/', class_mode='binary')
test_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('data/test/', class_mode='binary')

# confirm the iterator works
batchX, batchy = train_it.next()
print('Batch shape=%s, min=%.3f, max=%.3f' % (batchX.shape, batchX.min(), batchX.max()))
```

And pytorch has the [DataLoader class](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader). Example:

```py
# normalize data inputs
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),  # Transform to tensor
    transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))  # Min-max scaling to [-1, 1]
])

# load train/test sets
trainset = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(root=data_dir, train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
testset = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(root=data_dir, train=False, download=True, transform=transform)

# define classes
classes = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat', 'Sandal',
           'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']

# initialize train/test generators
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=5, shuffle=False)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! That helps a lot! Now, I have another question. Maybe, you can take a look to this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61042900/train-validation-data-split-labels-available-but-no-classes